# Magento custom head code

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

How can I add a custom code i.e. Facebook retargetting or conversion pixel, etc. to a  section of a SPECIFIC page? (not global)

I am using the latest magento version.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how specific the page is? Like is it for only one specific product, or just the product page in general (all products), or a specific category, or the home page, etc?

Comment: Hi, it is a thank you page with text only. no products on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this cleanly using Magento’s layout system. Create or modify the `local.xml` file in your current theme’s `layout` subdirectory. Add a new layout update like this:

```
<!-- Add Facebook retargeting pixel on success page. -->
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/template" name="fb_retargeting" template="tracking/fb_retargeting.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Notice that this layout update is targeting the `<checkout_onepage_success>` handle, which corresponds to the `/checkout/onepage/success` page. If you need to target a different page, you have to figure out the layout handle for that page. [The handle is created by combining the route name, controller name, and controller method into a single underscore-separated string](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates).

Now you just need to create your template file in your current design’s `template` subdirectory. In my above example, the template being referenced should be created at: `app/design/frontend/.../template/tracking/fb_retargeting.phtml`. You would just put the markup for your tracking pixel in that file.

Answer (score 0):

1) If its going to be a CMS pages you can add in the design tab Layout Update XML and add custom xml code, for example

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="module/block" name="module" template="module/view.phtml" ></block>
</reference>
```

2) If this need to be in other pages, you can add same code in local.xml of your theme file

Comment: ok, I have done step 1. what's next? where do I enter the custom javascript so it is applied to this page only? Why are you referring to this page module/view.phtml ? thanks

Comment: <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>yourscript.js</script></action>
            </reference>

Answer (score 0):

go to app/design/frontend/base/your theme/template/page/html/head.phtml

```
    $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
    $url = Mage::getSingleton('core/url')->parseUrl($currentUrl);
    $path = $url->getPath();

    if($path == your specic page url){ 
        your code. 
    }
```

Comment: I have done it but the code is added to every single page. I need it to be added to a specific page. Maybe I am specifying the path wrong. 

if($path == /thank-you/)

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just put path condition and add code in that if condition and it'll work.